# Why will this form not submit in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am just learning Laravel and following the Laravel 5.7 from scratch (I am using 5.8)course from Laracasts. 
We create a new controller that should handle tasks associated with a project. We show the tasks on the details page for the particular project. All of this works so far. Then, we add a checkbox that indicates when a task has been completed. The checkbox is in a form that submits on change. 
This is my form code.

```
@section('content')
  <div class ="col col-md-6">
    <form  action="/tasks/{{$task->id}}" method="POST">
      @method("PATCH")
      @csrf
      <label class = "checkbox" for="completed">Completed</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="completed" onChange="this.form.submit()">
    </form>
  </div>
 @endsection
```

Currently, in my Controller, I have the function but am just trying to see if it is hitting the function so I die and dump. Or that is what it should do anyway..

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProjectTasksController extends Controller
{
    public function update(){
      dd("hello");
    }
}
```

And, in my web.php file, this is how I have my route set up.

```
Route::patch('/tasks/{task}', 'ProjectTasksController@update');
```

Yet, it is not working. When I check one of the checkboxes, the URL changes to this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/projects/1?_method=PATCH&_token=0menrjzIOdiSn0SEu51unY114oKU8kZ2i2B5zy4p&completed=on
```

So, it is like it is not hitting the route though the route is defined. I don't know what I am doing wrong as I have done exactly what is being done in the video and so I am stuck.
Can someone tell me what is wrong with this?

Comment: That is how Laravel works... I am using the exact same thing in another form and it works fine. With Laravel, you have to submit the form with a POST method but then you have to call the patch method to update.

Comment: @Premisoft you don't **HAVE** to call the PATCH method to update, it's just an HTTP convention, you can still use regular POST request to update or delete just fine

Comment: By the way, I just copy pasted your code to a Laravel app and it's working correctly, you might have an issue somewhere else

Comment: I also checked your code and it's working correctly from my side.

Comment: I don't know if this means anything, but I just realized this is only an issue with the first task. Any other tasks work fine. As I said, I am just starting Laravel and so I am confused by this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**change patch to post**

```
Route::patch('/tasks/{task}', 'ProjectTasksController@update');
```

**to**

```
Route::post('/tasks/{task}', 'ProjectTasksController@update');
```

and then add parameter

```
  public function update(){
      dd("hello");
    }
```

**to**

```
public function update($task){
      dd("hello");
    }
```

1. php artisan route:clear
2. php artisan route:cache
3. php artisan config:clear

Comment: I did all of the above. But when I used php artisan route:cache, it returned the  error above. Still have the same problem LogicException  : Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure.

Comment: 1. Delete all files from /bootstrap/cache except .gitignore and then run php artisan config:cache with composer dump-autoload

Comment: Just tried that. Still same issue. Weird thing is that right now, I have three tasks in the database. So, this is only an issue on the first task. The other two tasks do exactly what they should. I have even tried recreating the entire blade file just in case there was something wrong in my code that I was missing. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Just change action like what I give <form action="{{url('tasks/' . $task->id)}}"......> and then try ,it may happen by url path,some time laravel blade does not work simple relative  path too so just add url()

Comment: That didn't work either. Let me tell you what I just did though. In trying to learn Laravel, I pushed myself ahead of this tutorial that I am following. So, I have auth utilized. Not on this page, but it is in use elsewhere in the application. So, just to try something different, I logged in. Now it works as it should. If I log out, it doesn't work correctly. So, the issue seems to be centered around the way I am using Auth. Not sure why or what is causing it though.

Comment: it may cause by **middleware**  because **middleware**  can prevent and allow unauthorized links what we wrote in middleware,i am using 5.6 version but you using 5.8 version  so in this update they may provided default **middleware**  for security reason or you did wrongly anything in middleware while you learn so i think you should learn about **middleware**  for your better understand.

Comment: I think that is it as well. When I removed the route for my admin page where I am defining a middleware file, it seems to work fine. Thank you very much for your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue with the route cache, have your tried clearing your cache using artisan?

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

These are the 4 commands to clear all the cache Laravel may have for your `configs`, `routes` and `views`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a form inside a form or rather a form component is wrapped in with other form tags; I had the same problem.
You may find out in the parent blade you have a form and the child(medical-info-components.payment) blade that is alone has a form also.

```
<div>

<fieldset>
    
    @if ($stripe)
    <div class="card-body">
        <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
        <hr>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <strong class="text-bold" style="font-size:20px;">Make Payment of
                        {{$currency}} {{$price}}
                    </strong>
                    <br>
                    <strong style="font-size:20px;">Please make payments by entering 
                your Credit or Debit
                        Card</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6" style="float:right;">

            <form action=" {!! action('\App\Http\Controllers\PaymentController@store') !!}" method="POST"
                id="payment-form" ata-cc-on-file="false"
                data-stripe-publishable-key="{{env('pk_test_')}}"
                enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                {{--  <input type="hidden" class="" name="stripeToken" id="stripeToken" wire:model.lazy="stripeToken" />  --}}
                <div class="form-row">
                    <label for="card-element">
                        Your Name
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" wire:model.lazy='name'
                        placeholder="Enter Your Name" id="">
                    <label for="card-element">
                        Your Payable Amount
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" name="grandTotal" class="form-control" wire:model.lazy='amount'
                        placeholder="Enter Your Amount" id="">
                    <label for="card-element">
                        Credit or debit card
                    </label>
                    <div id="card-element" class="form-control">
                        <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                    </div>

                    <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
                    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
                </div>

                <input type="button" class="previous action-button-previous btn btn-dark"
                    style="margin-left: -11rem; margin-top:15px;" value="Previous" wire:click='previousStep' />
                <input type="submit" class="next action-button btn btn-primary"
                    style="float:right; margin-top:15px;" value="Confirm" />

            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
    @elseif($paypal) @elseif($mpesa) @endif

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

        </div>
    </div>

</fieldset>
```

And then inside the mother component, you may have this

```
<div>
<!-- call -->
<section class="slice">
    <div class="container" id="grad1">
        <div class="row justify-content-center mt-0">
            <div class="col-12 text-center p-0 mt-3 mb-2">
                <div class="card px-0 pt-4 pb-0 mt-3 mb-3 border-0 rounded-lg">
                    <div class="card-body px-5">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 mx-0">
                                {{--  <form id="msform">  --}}
                                    <!-- progressbar -->

                                    @livewire('medical-info-components.payment')

                                {{--  </form>  --}} <!--You see here we have form wrapping our component that has form, you need to take it down-->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```